# Appending row just in tbody with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a problem when I try to do the next:

```
$('#period tbody').append(register);
```

*period* is the id of the table. I have a sub-table inside *thead* and another inside *tbody*.

```
register = "<tr class='input' id='regin'><td class='tab-but'><button class='del-row' type='button'>X</button></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-proj'><select><option>Select project...</option><c:forEach items='${projects}' var='project'>"
     + "<option value='${project.ID}'>${project.name}</option>;</c:forEach></select></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-odd'><input class='monin type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-none'><input class='tuein type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-odd'><input class='wedin type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-none'><input class='thuin type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-odd'><input class='friin type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-end'><input class='satin type='number'></td>"
     + "<td class='tab-end'><input class='sunin type='number'></td></tr>";
```

When I create dynamically the new row it duplicates in both (thead and tbody), I just wanna to create under tbody.

Any idea?

Comment: share value of register

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution adding an id to tbody, so instead of

```
$('#period tbody').append(register);
```

I use

```
$('#body-table').append(register);
```

It works fine but I'd like to understand why dind't work on the other way.